# Kick starting the reputation and voting on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, voting, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

If you need a reputation of 15 to vote and you get reputation by people voting for you then how did anyone ever get any points when Stack Overflow first started out and everyone had 0 points?

Comment: True - didn't think of that.

Comment: Indeed.  Or getting your answer accepted.

Comment: I see.  I thought I had discovered some great flaw, lol.

Comment: Jon Skeet upvoted all the early answers and questions.  No one tells Jon Skeet when he can or cannot vote.

Comment: @random I think [this is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) probably the better dupe since it describes the relaxed reputation requirements during the Private and Public betas which I'm guessing were true during the SO beta